# Highlight multiple items in android list view when selected

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, kotlin, contacts

I have a listview with all the user's contacts and their relevant phone numbers. I want them to be able to select multiple cells/rows and then the list must highlight the select contacts so that the user does not lose there state.

I have a custom adapter setup that looks as follows.

```
public class ContactsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "ContactsListAdapter";

    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public Resources res;
    ContactsModel tempValues=null;
    int i=0;

    public ContactsListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d, Resources resLocal) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        res = resLocal;

        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (data != null) {
            if(data.size()<=0)
                return 1;
            return data.size();
        } else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (data != null)
            return position;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (data != null)
            return position;
        return 0;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        public RelativeLayout containerView;
        public TextView fullname;
        public TextView phone_number;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ContactsListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ContactsListAdapter.ViewHolder();
            holder.fullname = vi.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            holder.phone_number = vi.findViewById(R.id.contactPhoneNumber);
            holder.containerView = vi.findViewById(R.id.containerView);

            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder=(ContactsListAdapter.ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(data.size()<=0)
        {
            //holder.username.setText("No Data");

        }
        else
        {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = ( ContactsModel ) data.get( position );

            holder.fullname.setText(tempValues.getFullname());
            holder.phone_number.setText(tempValues.getPhone_number());

        }
        return vi;
    }

}
```

Then I have an async task that goes and gets the contacts from the device and then updated the adapter as follows.

```
class Contacts(context: Context, listview : ListView, adapter : ContactsListAdapter?, CustomListViewValuesArr : ArrayList<ContactsModel>, progress : ProgressBar?) : AsyncTask<Unit, Unit, Unit>() {

    val context : Context = context
    var listview : ListView = listview
    var adapter : ContactsListAdapter? = adapter
    var CustomListViewValuesArr : ArrayList<ContactsModel> = CustomListViewValuesArr
    var holder : ArrayList<ContactsModel>? = null
    var progress : ProgressBar? = progress

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        progress!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        progress!!.animate()
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Unit?) {

        var obj : JSONObject = JSONObject()

        var contactsModels : ArrayList<ContactsModel> = arrayListOf()

        var cr : ContentResolver = context.contentResolver

        var cur : Cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null)

        if ((if(cur != null) cur.getCount() else 0) > 0) {
            while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))

                val name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))

                if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {

                    val pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            arrayOf(id), null)

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        var phoneNo : String = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replace("\\D", "")

                        obj.put(name, phoneNo)

                        var model : ContactsModel = ContactsModel()
                        model.fullname = name
                        model.phone_number = phoneNo
                        contactsModels.add(model)
                    }

                    pCur.close()

                }
            }

            holder = contactsModels

        }

    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Unit?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        CustomListViewValuesArr.clear()
        CustomListViewValuesArr.addAll(holder!!)
        //Log.d(TAG, "Adapter Notify")
        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

        progress!!.visibility = View.GONE
    }

}
```

This is my best solution so far to hightlight to selected contacts but the problem is that when you scroll it fails to set the background for the rest of the contacts.

```
contactsListView!!.setOnItemClickListener(object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val items = contactsListView!!.getCheckedItemPositions()

            for (i in 0 until contactsListView!!.getAdapter().getCount()) {

                if (items.get(i) == true) {

                    parent!!.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hapningGrey))
                    val contactName = parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contactName)
                    val phoneNumber = parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contactPhoneNumber)

                    var itemPhoneNumber : String = phoneNumber.text.toString()
                            .replace("(", "")
                            .replace(")", "")
                            .replace(" ", "")
                            .replace("-", "")

                    if (nominatedList.contains(itemPhoneNumber) == false) {
                        nominatedList.add(itemPhoneNumber)
                    }

                } else {

                    parent!!.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                    val contactName = parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contactName)
                    val phoneNumber = parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contactPhoneNumber)

                    var itemPhoneNumber : String = phoneNumber.text.toString()
                            .replace("(", "")
                            .replace(")", "")
                            .replace(" ", "")
                            .replace("-", "")

                    if (nominatedList.contains(itemPhoneNumber) == true) {
                        nominatedList.remove(itemPhoneNumber)
                    }

                }


            }

            Log.d(TAG, nominatedList.toString())

        }
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Add to longClickListener

```
view.selected=true
```

Add to holder a isSelected field as boolean

```
var isSelected=false
```

Add to adapter

```
holder.isSelected=vi.isSelected
if (holder.isSelected)
  vi.background=ContextCompat.getColor(vi.context,R.color.blue)
```